# How to find URLs in a string with PHP?

Tags: php, url

I know there is `filter_var()` but I don't want to validate a URL, I want to spot them in a whole text (*e.g.* a tweet). So you got any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See it here:

http://saturnboy.com/2010/02/parsing-twitter-with-regexp/

Comment: @sexyprout Regexps are normally delimited with /slashes/, but that can make things difficult to read if you're actually looking for slashes in the regular expression (as you are, to parse `http://www.example.com/whatever...`) because you have to escape the slash characters in the expression. To make it easier, you can use any character you want to delimit your regular expression. In this case, "@" is being chosen as an arbitrary character that doesn't need to appear in the expression itself. For example, the regular expressions `/http:\/\/(.*)\/(.*)/` and `@http://(.*)/(.*)@` are equivalent

Answer (score 2):

Using a regex should take care of that.
This basically works for Twitter

```
$text=$a_twitter_message;
preg_match_all("/http:\/\/(.*?)\/? /", $text, $link_match);
var_dump($link_match);
```

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression solutions are fine, but here's another simple way: use strpos.

```
if(strpos($text, "http://") !== false) {
   print "url found";
}
```

use stripos for case-insensitive.

Also, be aware that the other regular expression examples don't check for 'https' or just urls starting with 'www' only!

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: And how to extract URLs then?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your post..it said 'spot', not extract..But I guess extract makes more sense ;)